# Storing phone number in user info/user profile without authentication in Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I'm siging in users with the Email/Password method on Firebase. I'm not interested in switching to phone authentication. That being said, I'd like to store the users phone number in their profile for later access.

I know I can store it like so:

Users/UID/PhoneNumber: XXXXXX

But I'd like to be able to access it at a later date without having to query for that user id. Rather I'd like to store it so I can get at it through currentUser.phoneNumber or something similar.

I know there updateProfile which takes a displayName and profilePic but the documentation doesn't seem to allow phoneNumber. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: in order to get the user phone number you will need to prompt any sort of dialog to bring to the user, so the user can type the number press "ok" and send it to the database, or you will need to use phoneAuth in order to get it automatically

Comment: @GastónSaillén but can I Store it In the user profile or user info?

Comment: yes, for sure, you can store the number but you cant access directly the user phone number without firebase phone auth, you will need to prompt the user to put the numer

Comment: So I have to store it somewhere In My database and query it each time.

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: "I'd like to store the users phone number in their profile for later access." - if you want to store it in their profile (im thinking about a firebase node in your database) you will need to query that user to get the phone

Comment: the thing is that with a dialog to tell the user to put their number, you can not validate if that number is right , you will need firebase phone auth to be sure that that number is from that user

Comment: I’m trying to be able to access the phone number through the user data. Auth.currentUser.phoneNumber so that I don’t have to get user ID and use that to query the database just to get the phoneNumber. But since I’m using expo I can’t use PhoneAuth so I can’t store it that way. I was wondering if I could store the phoneNumber somewhere in the userInfo or userProfile same way you can store displayName and ProfilePic

Comment: I don’t care if the number is the persons actual number (its only there to help them so if they put the wrong number okay.) but I want quick access to it without having to query for it. Aka I want it in the userInfo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't** get the user phone doing something like this:

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber();
```

as you cannot access directly the user phone without implementing [Firebase Phone Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth?).

Since you don't care if that number is from that person, a workaround would be doing an `AlertDialog` or an `EditText` to prompt the user to type the desired number you want to store, and yes, you will need to query it each time since you are not getting it from `Auth`.

The only way possible of getting the user phone number in the userInfo as you say without querying the database is implementing Phone Auth.

> Doing the workaround there is no guarantee that the phone number
>   entered by the user is the right one

Comment: That annoying. But thanks for the help! I'd love to use Phone Auth but not possible wwith Expo :/

Comment: i get you, but imagine this, if we could just get any user that registers in our app their phone number with just doing google sign in or sign in with email, it willd be without their concent and that is not good since they dont know you are taking their numbers, to do this you need to implement any sort of auth that the user will accept to give their numbers.

Comment: by the way, doing it hardcoded with a dialog will do the job for your expo :)

Comment: How? I tried looking everywhere. I can't use ApplicationVerifier cause it doesn't work through expo. That would be amazing

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the admin sdk `updateUser` API: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user

```
admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {
  phoneNumber: "+11234567890",
}).then(function(userRecord) {
  // User updated. You can now get this from client:
  // FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber();
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Error occurred.
});
```